# Retrieve get request parameters in socket.io

Tags: node.js, sockets, socket.io

Imagine I have *socket.io* on server and I am listening for connections:

```
io.on('connection', function (socket) {

//.....How do I get the www.myserver.com:3000/address=123&name=John string here?
...    
}
```

Now, imagine client types such URL in browser:

```
www.myserver.com:3000/address=123&name=John
```

Now, **from within the `connection` event handler above** how do I get the URL
client typed?

I am thinking to use "referer" property present inside the 
`socket.handshake`. Is this right way to do it?